# Python Type Hints for temporary Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I declare and set temporary variables in Python? I am using online GDB for Python 3. A minimal code example is below. The debugger states this is a syntax error.  The error message is below.

```
def main():
    a:int 
    a = 0 
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For that piece of code the error message is below.

```
  File "main.py", line 4
    a:int
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also, I have tried another solution in the comments which does not work on GDB for Python 3. The code is below.

```
def main():
    a: int = 0 
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For the later example, the error message is below.

```
  File "main.py", line 4                                                                                   
    a: int = 0                                                                                     
     ^                                                                                 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

A correct version that does not produce syntax error is below.

```
def show(a:int)->None:
    print(str(a))

def main():
    a = 0
    show(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Variables are scoped and last as long as they are still in scope. Maybe look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: Why on earth would you want to type hint something in a debugger? In any case, that is exactly what you've done in your `main`

Comment: @AkashPatel I didn't downvote, but your question is not very clear at all, and your code contains an answer already

Comment: What is not clear about it?

Comment: Do you want to declare your variable like this: `a: int = 0` ?

Comment: That also does not work. I have put the spaces exactly the same way.

Comment: What problem are you observing with the code you have posted?

Comment: I observe syntax error on that exact piece of code.

Comment: Then say that in your question and give all the details you have about the error.

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Then why does the code compile if the type hint is on a paramter?

Comment: @AkashPatel because typing is valid for function arguments and not variables...  also, as an aside, code doesn't compile in python.

Comment: [Function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) are permitted in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/):

```
def foo():
    x:int
    x=0
```

were added in Python 3.6. In earlier versions of Python, they are invalid syntax.

Whereas [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

```
def foo(x:int) -> None:
    pass
```

were valid in earlier versions, since 3.0.